# How to make a custom reciever app for google chromecast?

Tags: chromecast

I want to make a chromecast application to play videos on the Chrome Device. I've downloaded a sender and receiver application from GITHUB. When I use Default or Styled Media Receiver Application, it's working fine. But I want to make a custom receiver for my application. I can't find any tutorial for that. Are there any steps that I should follow to make the receiver for the chromecast device.

I am following following code of GITHUB
https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

but its not working for custom reciever.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Look through our documentations [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/), there are sections for custom receivers and senders. Then look though the GitHub samples. If after doing those you still have specific coding questions, come back here and ask.

Comment: I have downloaded the "cast videos-android" sender application code from github along with "cast custom receiver".

I have put the receiver in my local server and also registered both application and chromecast device. I have given the localhost address to load the receiver while publishing the application.

I have changed the application id in the code which I got after publishing the custom receiver. while running the sender app casting was successful. But when playing the videos it shows the error "failed to launch" and the chromecast tv screen shows the message "Activity Aborted".

Comment: Can you please suggest me some steps to resolve this. As I am new to chrome cast, i just have basic knowledge of it. And if possible can you provide the sample application to play video with simple custom receiver.

Comment: When you downloaded and run the CastVideos-android, without any modification, did it work? 

When you see an error on TV screen, the best way to diagnose that is to use chrome debugger to look at the console log. Details can be found on our documentation page under Custom Receiver.

Comment: Yes, it worked but only with default receiver and styled receiver but when i used the custom receiver, it started showing the mentioned error. Even i was unable to open the debugger.

Comment: if your device is registered for your App Id, then you should be able to debug through the chrome debugger IF your app is running on the chromecast. Start from Cast-Player-Sample as your receiver and update that to make it fit your needs.

Comment: In the Setup Instructions, it was mentioned to upload the receiver.html to a website that can be accessed from your Chromecast. But there i didn't find the receiver.html.

I have one more doubt.. is the receiver application specific for a sender application [after providing the appropriate app id] or we can use any receiver that can play video for our application. Initially i just want to test to play video using custom media receiver.

Comment: When you registered your app, you provided a URL. That URL should point to your receiver and should either be publicly available, or if you are using a private network (e.g. your own LAN network), you would then need to use IP address when providing the URL in the Dev Console so that your chromecast device can find your receiver.

Comment: I have done the same. It is also accessible when I try it from the browser.

Comment: Being accessible from a browser is not really adequate; a normal desktop browser uses your DNS to resolve so a local name can be resolved in that case; Chromecast uses Google's DNS so a local name is not going to be resolved.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are using the CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM as a sample? Does your media have DRM protection? If not, use Cast-Player-Sample

Comment: Sir, in the setup instructions of Cast-Player-Sample, it is mentioned to put the URL of Receiver.html but on that app, Receiver.html was not there.

Comment: Updated that README file.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)